# Is there a JavaScript shell?

Tags: shell, shell-script, javascript

Recently I've been working with JS and I'm very enthusiastic about this language. I know that there is *node.js* for running JS at server side, but is there a shell that uses JS as a scripting language? If such thing exists, how usable & stable is it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Does this look desirable to you?

```
// Replace macros in each .js file
cd('lib');
ls('*.js').forEach(function(file) {
  sed('-i', 'BUILD_VERSION', 'v0.1.2', file);
  sed('-i', /.*REMOVE_THIS_LINE.*\n/, '', file);
  sed('-i', /.*REPLACE_LINE_WITH_MACRO.*\n/, cat('macro.js'), file);
});
cd('..');
```

If so, [*ShellJS*](http://documentup.com/arturadib/shelljs) could be interesting, it's

> a portable (Windows included) implementation of Unix shell commands on top of the Node.js API.

I'm unsure if this could be used as a full-featured login shell, though.  (Maybe with some wrapping?)

You could argue that it's not really a shell, but do you know [TermKit](https://github.com/unconed/TermKit#readme)?  It's made of Node.js + Webkit, you could use JS to extend it (I guess); the shell language is still Bash(-ish).

Comment: Well, that looks cool! I'll give it a try.

Comment: I technically don't really consider this a shell because it doesn't follow the `cmd arguments` syntax. For example `psh` adds such syntax to the perl language from my understanding so it appears more like a typical shell http://gnp.github.io/psh  There might be a counter example but I haven't find it yet.

Comment: How would I set this as my login shell?  Again I want something like this but I'm just not convinced this is it.

Comment: Still bash-ish, we could use `sed({i:1}, 'BUILD_VERSION',  'v0.1.2', file)` instead. Would be better to use async functions with await, so parallel would be faster.

Comment: ShellJS link is broken.

Answer (score 10):

If you're on Ubuntu or any other debian based system, you may install rhino (from Mozilla.org).

```
sudo apt-get install rhino
```

It supplies js via alternatives:

```
=== /usr/bin/js is a symlink... following it
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Nov 21 08:54 /usr/bin/js -> /etc/alternatives/js
=== /etc/alternatives/js is a symlink... following it
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Nov 21 08:54 /etc/alternatives/js -> /usr/bin/rhino
=== /usr/bin/rhino is owned by package: rhino ===
```

So calling either ***rhino*** or ***js*** will give you a JavaScript shell.

**Edit (2014-06-30):**

***rhino*** is good to quickly test some javascript code in a file, but it is not an interactive shell, so it doesn't support GNU readline style of editing.  For interactive work, you may prefer `nodejs`: on Ubuntu/debian `sudo apt-get install nodejs`.  This should provide a more interactive `js` shell (invoke using the command `js`) where you can edit lines and recall history with the up/down arrow-keys.  For a longer list of options, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Shells

Answer (score 9):

[Mozilla INC offers a `javascript` shell](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SpiderMonkey/1.8.5) : see [Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell)

Example of a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) shell in a system [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

```
$ js
js> str = "welcome on *nix side" 
"welcome on *nix side"
js> str.indexOf("nix");          
12
js>
```

No problems detected since I use it for testing purpose.

Comment: This is available on some/many linux distros now as a `js` package.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome and Firefox, if you press F12 it brings up developer tools. Over there you could find a tab called console, where you could type and test JavaScript scripts. It has code completion and other features too.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. I've asked about **UNIX** shell. But thanks for the willing to help anyway.

Comment: This answers the question, "_is there a shell that uses JS as a scripting language?_". Nothing in the question talks about an alternative to `bash` or `zsh` (etc.)