# Using node.js and shelljs as interactive shell

Tags: shell, node.js, javascript

Following the answer given at [Is there a JavaScript shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58011/is-there-a-javascript-shell)

That requires me to always execute

```
var shell=require("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/shelljs");
```

It seems like node forces execute a script and read stdin to be mutally exclusive so i tried

```
cat ~/.jshrc /dev/stdin | node
```

Which works expect that node output is not printed immediately. Can the pipe echo earlier or is there another way to do it like adding a special file that is always executed?