# Curl to grab the page after complete load

Tags: linux, command-line, curl

I have a url which takes some time to load completely. But when I use curl to download the link as html, it download the html at the real time before loading page completely I mean complete execution of JavaScript. Please help me how to stop the curl until the page is loaded completely or start the download of the page after 1 minute.

Comment: curl does not understand JavaScript.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: You should make that an answer.  Although OP may not like it, it's the truth and a good answer which others will upvote.

Answer (score 6):

`curl` won't "wait" to interpret your Javascript because `curl` does not understand JavaScript; JavaScript is always done on the client side, and usually browsers that have JavaScript engines/know how to run JavaScript.

So `curl` will see it only as block as text, and leave it as it is.

Please do note this behaviour is not unique to `curl` e.g. in the Linux command line, `wget`, `nc` and `lynx` (and others) won't understand JavaScript too.

`links` seems to have a buggy JavaScript support (if compiled), however it is a text browser for interactive use.

If you do not mind scripting, have a look at [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org)

> phantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. It
>   has fast and native support for various web standards: DOM handling,
>   CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG.

Comment: Please have a look at the related question, that while refers to a Javascript shell, delves around the same theme, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58011/is-there-a-javascript-shell

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful and useful info. So is there any other method to download a page without opening browser?

Comment: it is in the answer. phantomJS, but it appears to be scriptable. I think you have a demo script in the page, that may (or not) suit your needs.